# ERROR Conterface Interface up or insufficient permissions: Too many open files in system

Tags: terminal, wifi, wlan, mac-address

What does this mean 'Too many open files in system'. I have set ulimit -n 70000 so there isn't a limitation...

```
[ERROR] Could not change MAC: interface up or insufficient permissions: Too many open files in system
```

Comment: What command is producing that, or which log are you finding it in?

Comment: macchanger -r wlan0

Comment: Are you root when you run it?  If not try doing it with `sudo`

Comment: I'm in root yes. I think it has to do with the card/driver